# Is there a "texbox content changed" DOM event?

Tags: html, events, dom

Every time I need to write a piece of JavaScript which monitors an input box, I usually end up doing something like:

```
$("#field").keyup(myHandler).keydown(myHandler).change(myHandler);
```

It’s not perfect, but it usually works in most cases, and so I move on. I just happen to have a little bit of time to investigate this properly. Probably the major problem is that is does not catch edits done via mouse (right-click + paste/cut). Also, it’s not really what I want. This captures all cursor movements and other keyboard events which I’m not really interested in. So the question is:

**Is there a reliable cross-browser event which is fired every time *after* the content of an input or textarea changes?**

During a brief search, I found the [onpropertychange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956%28VS.85%29.aspx) and DOMAttrModified events. But apart from the fact they don’t work in all browsers, they don’t seem to be fired when editing an input or textarea.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why is `onchange` not an option here? Does it fire too early?

Comment: It fires too late; it fires only when the textbox is left.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like at least the latest versions of Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari all support the `cut` and `paste` events, which are triggered immediately after text is cut or pasted in a given input element. The events are triggered by keyboard *and* mouse interactions. Listening for a combination of these and other events should provide the functionality you are looking for.

```
$("#foo").bind("keyup keydown change paste cut", handler);
```

I tested this on a Mac in Firefox 3.6, Chrome 5.0 (dev), and Safari 4, and on Windows in Firefox 3.5 and IE8.

Comment: Good tip. Why not keypress instead of keyup, keydown?

Comment: Depending on the browser, the `keypress` event is not triggered in all cases. For example, when the Control key is pressed, `keydown` and `keyup` will be triggered, but `keypress` will *not*. I suppose it doesn't matter in this case, but since the OP's example used `keydown` and `keyup`, I did too. Using `keypress` would work just as well here.

Comment: Thank you, very useful tip. Also, I did not know you can simply concatenate event names like this: $("#foo").bind("keyup keydown change paste cut", handler).